# Django deployment in Heroku: Fails in createsuperuser : django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heroku

There has been a lot of stackoverflow question regarding this particular error but I think none has the similar situation that I have. I've been following djangogirls heroku deployment tutorial, from database setup in `settings.py` ensuring that I have done it correctly.

I got the app up and running in the host. Trying to access admin now, it still has the Operational Error for auth_user. Therefore I thought that I might've just gone wrong with the migration. So following these steps I did this:

1.) python manage.py makemigrations

2.) python manage.py migrate

3.) git add . , git commit -m "-" , git push heroku master

4.) heroku run python manage.py makemigrations

5.) heroku run python manage.py migrate

And now the last step, everything fails here, saying that there is still things to migrate.

6.) heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser

The steps that I did are the suggestions that they presented and was accepted but it can't seem to work in my case. Any ideas?

`git push heroku master`

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 584 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        61 static files copied to '/tmp/build_82c26be81e84293089f1ac30a26227e2/hope/staticfiles', 24 post-processed.
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 162.1M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v23
remote:        https://plexus-test.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/plexus-test.git
   05985ed..ef721b3  master -> master
```

`heroku run python manage.py makemigrations`

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W001) Your URL pattern '^$' uses include with a regex ending with a '$'. Remove the dollar from the regex to avoid problems including URLs.
blog.Post.created_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
    HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`
Migrations for 'blog':
  blog/migrations/0004_auto_20170810_1400.py
    - Alter field created_date on post
```

`heroku run python manage.py migrate`

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W001) Your URL pattern '^$' uses include with a regex ending with a '$'. Remove the dollar from the regex to avoid problems including URLs.
blog.Post.created_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
    HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying blog.0001_initial... OK
  Applying blog.0002_auto_20170808_1512... OK
  Applying blog.0003_auto_20170810_1322... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

`heroku logs`

```
2017-08-11T06:49:26.623403+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with 
command `python manage.py migrate` by user
2017-08-11T06:49:38.089108+00:00 heroku[run.8604]: Awaiting client
2017-08-11T06:49:38.121068+00:00 heroku[run.8604]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2017-08-11T06:49:38.345055+00:00 heroku[run.8604]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-11T06:49:43.808801+00:00 heroku[run.8604]: Process exited with status 0
2017-08-11T06:49:43.823668+00:00 heroku[run.8604]: State changed from up to complete
```

`heroku run python manage.py showmigrations`

*Seems to be wrong here at this point already.*
Migrations said it was applied but showmigrations say otherwise

```
admin
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [ ] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [ ] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [ ] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [ ] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
blog
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_remove_post_created_date
contenttypes
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial
test_app
 (no migrations)
```

`heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser`

```
    System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W001) Your URL pattern '^$' uses include with a regex ending with a '$'. Remove the dollar from the regex to avoid problems including URLs.
blog.Post.created_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
    HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`

You have 16 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 96, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 148, in get_default_username
    auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

`settings.py`

```
    """
Django settings for hope project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '###'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    u'plexus-test.herokuapp.com',
    u'127.0.0.1'
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'test_app',
    'blog'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hope.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hope.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

*Edit: I'm running on virtualenv.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I ended up re-doing the whole setup and it went okay without any problems. Keeping the question here anyways just in case someone has the same problem and this is eventually answered better.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, everything was working fine on local machine,but heroku was giving this error while i was trying to create a superuser.

So, it got fixed added the following to **settings.py** :-

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

this will connect your local settings and apps with heroku.

Thanks, I hope this may help.

Comment: I read a ton of other answers and surprisingly this was the only thing that worked. Looks like DATABASE_URL needs some kind of config to work with Heroku. https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/ this works as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Heroku error is stated there...

> You have 16 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly
>   until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, blog,
>   contenttypes, sessions. Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

I would just run...

```
>>> python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: hmmm yes that's it. As I stated above I did the following step accordingly... again and again I do the migration as the error states yet everytime I get to the createsuperuser step it will state the same error

Comment: so your database tables need to be there before the createsuperuser it appears your tables are not there which is the problem, no superuser can be created without a user table.

Comment: Shouldn't the migrate command automatically create the tables? It did say that it "applied" the migrations. From admin, auth, contenttypes and session plus my models. I'm wondering if the warnings impede the creation of the tables from the migration.

Comment: I would try to be explicit with the migration... maybe say >>> python makemigrations auth than... >>> python migrate auth  if that does not work, than I would suggest you run your initial migrations and createsuperuser before adding models or apps to your project.  So before adding try running these migrations than add your blog.

Comment: "Shouldn't the migrate command automatically create the tables?" yes, but something is not working right with your setup.  I would definitely delete the database if possible, than run your initial migrations before adding your blog or test apps.

Comment: alright let me try that. I'll let you know if that works :)

Comment: I guess it just won't make the migrations unless the warnings are fixed.. I tried showmigration in between it doesn't get past (no changes) makemigrations/migrate

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lack of synchronization between the persistence layer and the model, due to some change in the structure of the database (maybe done manually). If it is the case you need to clean up and reset migrations before continue.

https://www.techiediaries.com/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-17-18-19-and-110/

I suggest you make sure if this could be your case. Be very careful if the application is production phase!!

Comment: thanks for this link. I'll be trying this out and let you know